# Why the given javascript code(log=>"ASDF") inside async block is executing twice , whereas the other statement (log=>"asdf once ") is executed once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The caller is from the reducer i am using for the app to dispatch actions for changing the state of the app

The fn

```
const AddFriendFirebase = async (name = "", current_uid) => {
  console.log("ASdf one");
  const { uid } = await getUserFromName(name);
  console.log("ASdf");
  createMessageDoc(current_uid, uid);
}
```

The caller

```
case ADD_FRIEND: {
  AddFriendFirebase(payload, state.current_uid);
  return state;
}
```

get UserFromName Fn

```
const getUserFromName = async (name) => {
  console.log("get name fn");
  const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("user_name", "==", name));
  const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
  if (!snapshot.docs[0]) {
    throw console.error("user not found!");
  }
  const user = snapshot.docs[0].data();

  return user;
};
```

Comment: Presumably, AddFriendFirebase is called twice but the second call of getUserFromName throws an error. It's hard to see without seeing what is calling the caller.

Comment: `console.error` outputs an exception to the developer console. It doesn't return anything. `throw console.error(...)` is wrong.